# Multiple forms of instances of an entity on one page - forms not created

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring MVC. I have a page with a listing of instances of Image entity class. Each image has a form with input field. The purpose of these input field is to edit an image url. But it gives an error:

```
InputTag - Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'image' available as request attribute
```

The error occurs when trying to open the page with the forms.

How to solve it?

**EDIT**

This is not a matter of POST Controller method, because the page of forms is not created because of the error. So I remove the part of the POST method from the question.

**EDIT END**

These are files and a bigger error message:

**tk/trzczy/gallery/controllers/ImageController.java**

```
package tk.trzczy.gallery.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import tk.trzczy.gallery.domain.Image;
import tk.trzczy.gallery.services.ImageService;
import tk.trzczy.gallery.services.ImageCategoryService;
import tk.trzczy.gallery.services.UserService;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.Date;

@Controller
public class ImageController {

    @Autowired
    private ImageService imageService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private ImageCategoryService imageCategoryService;

    @RequestMapping("/gallery/edit")
    public String getImagesToEdit(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("images", imageService.getAllImages());
        return "editGallery";
    }
}
```

---

**tk/trzczy/gallery/domain/Image.java**

```
package tk.trzczy.gallery.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "images")
public class Image implements BasicImage{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "mySeqGen6", sequenceName = "mySeq6", initialValue = 11, allocationSize = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "mySeqGen6")

    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 300)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String url;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="image_category_id")
    private ImageCategory imageCategory;

    @Column(name="datecreated", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private Date dateCreated;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        dateCreated = new Date();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }


    public Image() {}

    public Image(Integer id, String title, String url, User user) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Post{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", url='" + url + '\'' +
                ", date=" + dateCreated +
                '}';
    }

    public ImageCategory getImageCategory() {
        return imageCategory;
    }

    public void setImageCategory(ImageCategory imageCategory) {
        this.imageCategory = imageCategory;
    }
}
```

---

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/editGalleryPage.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="g" uri="/WEB-INF/date-format-tag.tld" %>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:url value="/resource/css/editGallery.css" />"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <ul id="sortable" class="list-unstyled" style="list-style: none;">
            <c:forEach items="${images}" var="image">
                <li class="list-todo">
                    <div class="main-todo-content" id="main-todo-content-${image.id}">
                        <form:form modelAttribute="image" action="/images/edit/${image.id}" id="image" class="image"
                                   method="post">
                            <form:input path="url" id="image-${image.id}" style="width: 525px;"
                                        class=" form:input-large"
                                        name='url' value="${image.url}"/>
                            <input type="submit">
                            <p><form:errors path="url" cssClass="alert alert-danger"/></p>
                        </form:form>

                        <img id="display-${image.id}" class="gallery" src="${image.url}" height="300px"
                             title="${image.title } / <g:dateFromNow date="${image.dateCreated}"></g:dateFromNow>">
                        <p id="image-${image.id}">${image.url}</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>tk.trzczy</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspect.version>1.9.2</aspect.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.8</jackson.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.2.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.5.2</c3p0.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- servlets and jps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--hibernate-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate-C3P0 Integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for rest services -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For Aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspect.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspect.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To Send Email -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--logging-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- To use the plugin goals in your POM or parent POM -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

```
[DEBUG] 2020-10-15 02:26:59.448 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
[DEBUG] 2020-10-15 02:26:59.448 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
[DEBUG] 2020-10-15 02:26:59.448 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] EntityPrinter - tk.trzczy.gallery.domain.ImageCategory{name=grafika, description=Wszelkie rysunki, id=1}
[DEBUG] 2020-10-15 02:26:59.448 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] EntityPrinter - tk.trzczy.gallery.domain.ImageCategory{name=szkic, description=Próby i projekty, id=2}
[DEBUG] 2020-10-15 02:26:59.448 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] EntityPrinter - tk.trzczy.gallery.domain.Image{dateCreated=2020-04-18 16:16:36.0, id=3, imageCategory=tk.trzczy.gallery.domain.ImageCategory#3, priority=1, title=girl, url=https://i.imgur.com/BAZsUIb.png}
[DEBUG] 2020-10-15 02:26:59.448 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] EntityPrinter - tk.trzczy.gallery.domain.Image{dateCreated=2020-01-15 11:16:27.0, id=2, imageCategory=tk.trzczy.gallery.domain.ImageCategory#2, priority=3, title=kobieta w kapeluszu, url=https://i.imgur.com/spMsvHe.png}
[DEBUG] 2020-10-15 02:26:59.448 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] EntityPrinter - tk.trzczy.gallery.domain.ImageCategory{name=kolor, description=Zdjęcia kolorowe, id=3}
[DEBUG] 2020-10-15 02:26:59.448 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] EntityPrinter - tk.trzczy.gallery.domain.Image{dateCreated=2019-12-15 22:14:54.0, id=1, imageCategory=tk.trzczy.gallery.domain.ImageCategory#1, priority=2, title=lanszaft gęślą, url=https://i.imgur.com/sZ64fVI.jpg}
[DEBUG] 2020-10-15 02:26:59.449 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] HibernateTransactionManager - Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(1547873543<open>)] after transaction
[DEBUG] 2020-10-15 02:26:59.451 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] TilesView - View name 'editGallery', model {images=[Post{id=3, title='girl', url='https://i.imgur.com/BAZsUIb.png', date=2020-04-18 16:16:36.0}, Post{id=1, title='lanszaft gęślą', url='https://i.imgur.com/sZ64fVI.jpg', date=2019-12-15 22:14:54.0}, Post{id=2, title='kobieta w kapeluszu', url='https://i.imgur.com/spMsvHe.png', date=2020-01-15 11:16:27.0}]}
[DEBUG] 2020-10-15 02:26:59.537 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5581ba6a
[ERROR] 2020-10-15 02:26:59.634 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] InputTag - Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'image' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'image' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:123) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:460) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:357) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:83) [spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.editGalleryPage_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(editGalleryPage_jsp.java:443) [ROOT/:?]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.editGalleryPage_jsp._jspService(editGalleryPage_jsp.java:249) [ROOT/:?]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71) [jasper.jar:9.0.38]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477) [jasper.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) [jasper.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) [jasper.jar:9.0.38]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:64) [log4j-web-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequestDispatcher.include(HeaderWriterFilter.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954) [jasper.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:496) [jasper.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:123) [tiles-request-jsp-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47) [tiles-request-api-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47) [tiles-request-api-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68) [tiles-request-api-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259) [tiles-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188) [tiles-template-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132) [tiles-template-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299) [tiles-jsp-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.tiles.template.baseLayoutForGalleryEdit_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(baseLayoutForGalleryEdit_jsp.java:231) [ROOT/:?]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.tiles.template.baseLayoutForGalleryEdit_jsp._jspService(baseLayoutForGalleryEdit_jsp.java:157) [ROOT/:?]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71) [jasper.jar:9.0.38]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477) [jasper.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) [jasper.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) [jasper.jar:9.0.38]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:64) [log4j-web-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequestDispatcher.forward(HeaderWriterFilter.java:172) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265) [tiles-request-servlet-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228) [tiles-request-servlet-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57) [tiles-request-api-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47) [tiles-request-api-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259) [tiles-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397) [tiles-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238) [tiles-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221) [tiles-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59) [tiles-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:147) [spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:317) [spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) [spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) [spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) [spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) [servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add model attribute in your controller like below one

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/images/edit/{imageId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Integer editImage(Model model, @PathVariable("imageId") int id) {
        Image image = new Image();
        image.setId(id);
        imageService.updateImage(image);
        model.addAttribute("image",image);
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Muthukumaran. Anyway it has not worked. I am still getting the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'image' available as request attribute`.